# replace reoccuring text in a string differently

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the String `$myString` and the content of the String is random times "foo", but I don't know how many times!
What I want to do is to add an unique number to every "foo".
For example: "foo foo foo" -> "foo1 foo2 foo3"

my current approach:
`$z = 0;
$myString = preg_replace ( '/foo/' , 'foo'.++$z, $myString);`
and this returns of course "foo1 foo1 foo1"

So my questions is: How do I replace reoccuring text in a string differently in PHP?

Thank you!
MasterBolle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with regex the way is to use `preg_replace_callback` *(there are a lot of examples in the PHP manual and SO)*.

Without regex, using `explode` and `array_reduce`:

```
$str = 'foosdfdsfdsfdfoofoosdfdsfdfoosdfoo';
$cnt = 0;
$result = array_reduce(explode('foo', $str), function($c,$i) use (&$cnt) {
    return $c === false ? $i : $c . 'foo' . ++$cnt . $i;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the occurrences of the word **foo** in your string and then add them with a number to each **foo** by looping the number of occurrences:

```
    $myString = 'foo foo foo';
    $counts = substr_count($myString, 'foo');
    $newString = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $counts; $i++) {
        $newString .= 'foo' . $i . ' ';
    }
```

Comment: If this doesn't fit your case, you can use `preg_replace_callback` and make a function that adds a number to the string, but you'll have to keep the current number in a global variable so you can increment it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myString = 'foo foo foo';
$i = 1;
echo $myString = preg_replace_callback ( '/foo/', 
                 function($str) use (&$i) {return $str[0].$i++; }, 
                 $myString); // foo1 foo2 foo3
```

[demo](https://eval.in/580347)